# Is it possible to set up a dedicated global DNS server locally or on a VPS?

Tags: networking, dns, vps

I'm interested in setting up a DNS server under my possession that is able to resolve hostnames on the web, in the same way as a public DNS such as 8.8.8.8 would do. My priority here is speed, followed by privacy.

Setting up a local DNS server, whether it be on a Linux/Windows based machine or somehow within the wireless router itself would seem like the best option to fulfill these requirements, as it would be both fast (0ms resolve times?) and private. Alternatively, I own a remote Linux-based VPS that is fairly close-by, which would account primarily for the privacy factor, but also would not use my home bandwidth to operate.

If it is possible to do locally (on my home network), what equipment, operating system, and software should I look into in order to make it happen? Is it viable (because I suspect it takes some bandwidth in order to keep up-to-date)?

Alternatively, would setting up this DNS server on a VPS be the better option? If so, what software or packages should I look into in order to make it work?

I also understand it may not be possible to do at all, in which case just let me know and I'll explore other DNS options.

Comment: Unless this is a learning project (or whatever), there's really no reason to do this, and if anything, you'll get worse performance from a DNS server you set up locally than you would from the DNS servers run by Google, or your ISP or OpenDNS, or whomever else.

Comment: Why is that? In my question, I reference speed to be priority followed by privacy. If the DNS server is literally located within my home network, I should be seeing 0-5ms resolve times (in theory!). If it was hosted locally or on a VPS, I could also be relatively certain I am the lone recipient of DNS traffic, and, as such, the information would not be sent to a public DNS where it could be logged or otherwise altered.

Comment: Okie Dokie.  But that DNS information has to come from somewhere, and the DNS server you have on your home network is going to have to fetch it... from those public DNS serves you don't want to use for some reason.  So all you've done is add 0-5 ms of latency to the situation.

Comment: I apologize if I'm missing something, but that doesn't seem to make sense. If I'm running a local DNS server, it IS true that it will have to update its DNS database from somewhere. However, in your reply, it seems as though the local DNS is nothing more than a proxy in that DNS request -> local DNS server -> public DNS, then return hostname. The implementation that we SHOULD be seeing would have the local DNS host a database that is updated regularly, so we'd see DNS request -> local DNS server, return hostname, and let the local server update DNS on its own time rather than mine.

Comment: Well, yeah, you are missing something.  How that "DNS database" is created.  It's not like you just download a database of DNS names... your DNS server will go out and fetch a DNS name when a client machine makes a DNS request, and generally cache (store) it until the TTL on the DNS record expires.  But your client computer can do that too... they have a DNS cache.  So you're really not changing much of anything with this approach.... your local DNS server *is* just a proxy for DNS requests.

Comment: Then this *does*, in fact, answer my question in that it is not a viable solution in improving speed or privacy in a home environment. The acquisition of the so-called DNS database was my biggest doubt from the start, and it sounds as though it is not possible to host this sort of database at all. If this local DNS server is nothing more than a DNS cache and proxy, it makes the most sense to just use a VPN and my computer's DNS cache if privacy is really that important, as it would result in a comparable speed decrease as the one you described. Good discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion in the comments, yes, this is possible, but no, it will not behave as you want/need it to.

If you were to set up a local DNS server (or set one up on a VPS), it would essentially act as a proxy server for your DNS requests.  There is not "DNS database" to download, so it would perform DNS lookups in response to client requests, cache them just as your clients would, and really provide you ne benefit.  Your DNS lookups would still be [theoretically] publicly viewable, and you wouldn't get any speed benefits, because the DNS lookups would still occur as you need them, they'd just be shifted to a server from your client computer... but either way, you'd have to send your requests out into the internet to find a DNS server that can answer your request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a home network will be enough but...

I have two VPS as TWO DNS server, and i'm happy with them. 8 one over Debian , the other ubuntu server.

Thinking in a very small infrastructure as was with my job ( a hosting)
Devices.

1. You will need more upload speed than download speed ( home network
   will not match this )
2. refrigeration system ( dns query don't heat that much )
3. Two main DNS servers ( at least)
4. Two backup server ( at least)
5. An enterprise router
6. A nice firewall
7. A load balancer

HW:
Any subsystem will be ok. my two DNS have:

1. only 1024 MB of memory. and its ok for me.
2. Intel, dual core 2.4hgz

They are relatively small, but have been working about 4 years and have never failed

Software
I prefer Linux. so you will consume less memory and nice control over your system.

OS:
You can go with Centos or Debian based systems whichever goes better with you
I have been testing ubuntu 14.04 LTS. and I like it, its very fast don't suggest you go into it already. lets wait a bit bugs appear.

DNS server
* BIND is the most common

*PowerDNS
you can try is which if I'm not wrong support dns registry via mysql. so you can create other subsystems easily

Others securities software's

Comment: I'm actually looking to set this up for home use, and, as such, a refrigeration system and four servers are far out of reach. I suspected it may take this amount of resources and therefore not be plausible, but, by the way you make it sound it IS possible on a VPS with the bandwidth and CentOS installed.

Comment: yes i commented what i have. so you smile with them xD they are small server but have been my friends for many year. and a lot of  zone records serving south and north america.

Comment: of course you can remove a few things like. to be 1 DNS without firewall, refrigeration , load balance and the enterprise router. if only you will reach it